# how to make path strings in code file system independent?

Tags: c#

I realized that my code has a lot of paths of the form C:\folder\pathtofile, and I was wondering what is typically done to allow code to be usable under different file systems?

I was hoping there was some environment property I could check in C# that would give me either forward slash or backslash in order to create new path strings.

Comment: See `Path.Combine` and `Path.PathSeparator`

Comment: path should not be hard coded in any case - use `app.config` or some other mechanism.

Comment: well, i was assuming that you have to generate the original config file at some point. anyway thanks for all the advice

Comment: @NZI `Path.PathSeperator` is the wrong field, that is the field for separating multiple entiries in a `PATH=` environment variable, default value of `;`. the one you likely meant to say was `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the commands [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to combine strings together using the path separator or if you need more manual control [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you the platform specific character.

```
public static string GetConfigFilePath()
{
    //Returns "C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming"
    // or "C:/Users/{Username}/AppData/Roaming" depending on CLR running.
    var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

    //Returns "C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\MyProgramName\MyConfigFile.xml"
    // or "C:/Users/{Username}/AppData/Roaming/MyProgramName/MyConfigFile.xml"  depending on CLR running.
    var configPath = Path.Combine(appData, "MyProgramName", "MyConfigFile.xml");

    return configPath;
}
```

Comment: thanks. now to go back through my code everywhere and change things:( oh well. live and learn

Comment: The person who down voted, what about my answer is incorrect or unhelpful?